# Updating a variable in Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save two Strings (latitude and longitude) to pass them into a String 'URL'.

However, I keep getting null values once I exit the onLocationChanged method and I'm not sure why.

When inside the onLocationChanged method, the values appear to be stored and display correctly in the console, but further in the code they return null when in the console and I have no idea why. Can someone please help?

public void getTransport(View v) {

```
     String[] requiredPermissions = {
             Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
             Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
             Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
     };

     boolean ok = true;

     for (int i = 0; i < requiredPermissions.length; i++) {
         int result = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, requiredPermissions[i]);
         if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
             ok = false;
         }
     }

     if (!ok) {
         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, requiredPermissions, 1);
         // that last parameter MUST be >0, or it fails silently
         System.exit(0);
     } else {
         // doStuffThatNeedsPermissions();
         LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
         lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
             @Override
             public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                 double lat = location.getLatitude();
                 double lng = location.getLongitude();

                 String latitude = Double.toString(lat);
                 //latitude = latitude.substring(0,6);
                 String longitude = Double.toString(lng);
                 //longitude = longitude.substring(0,6);

                 String URL = "http://10.0.0.2:8080/stations?latitude=" + latitude +"&longitude=" + longitude + "&type=all";

                 System.out.println(URL);

             }

             @Override
             public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
             }

             @Override
             public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
             }

             @Override
             public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
             }
         });

     }

     System.out.println(URL);
     ConnectivityManager ConnMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo networkInfo = ConnMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
     if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
     {
         // fetch data


         Log.d("test", "TEST");

         AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask(this);

         //task.execute;
         task.execute(URL);
     }
     else
     {
         //output.setText(" test ");
     }
 }
```

Thank you in advance for any advice,

Answer (score 1):

This is a threading issue. Your code to return the location is evaluated before the code to set the fields, thats why its null.

Separate the two ideas:

```
public void logLocation(View v){
    System.out.println("LAT IS: "+ lati);
    System.out.println("Long IS: "+ longi);
}

public void getTransport(View v){
    getLocation();
}

// Get current location method
private void getLocation() {
    String[] requiredPermissions = {
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    };

    boolean ok = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < requiredPermissions.length; i++) {
        int result = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, requiredPermissions[i]);
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ok = false;
        }
    }

    if (!ok) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, requiredPermissions, 1);
        // that last parameter MUST be >0, or it fails silently
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        // doStuffThatNeedsPermissions();
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();

                TextView laititude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Lat);
                TextView longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Long);
                laititude.setText("" + lat);
                longitude.setText("" + lng);

                lati = (laititude.getText().toString());
                longi = (longitude.getText().toString());

                Log.d("Running", "looping");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I've shown you how its done simply, by adding another button. 1 button starts to monitor for new locations, and the other will print out the location (null if you press the button to early, but wait a bit and press it again).

---

Your alternative choice, is a callback mechanism across the threads:

```
interface MyCallback {
    void onLocationRetrieved(double lati, double longi);
}

public void getTransport(View v){
    getLocation(new MyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationRetrieved(double lati, double longi) {
           System.out.println("LAT IS: "+ lati);
           System.out.println("Long IS: "+ longi);
        }
    });
}

private void getLocation(MyCallback callback) {
    String[] requiredPermissions = {
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    };

    boolean ok = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < requiredPermissions.length; i++) {
        int result = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, requiredPermissions[i]);
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ok = false;
        }
    }

    if (!ok) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, requiredPermissions, 1);
        // that last parameter MUST be >0, or it fails silently
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        // doStuffThatNeedsPermissions();
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();

                callback.onLocationRetrieved(lat, lng);
                Log.d("Running", "looping");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Blundell, I'm still having issues, I have tried these two methods but it didn't work. I don't need the result to be visible on the app so I have tried removing the TextView and simply storing them as a string (I need them from input into a URL) but this still hasn't worked. Can you help?

Comment: print a Log msg inside of `onLocationChanged` does it ever get called?

Comment: yes, unfortunately it seems to call it several times, even when the location hasn't changed. (this was going to be something I attempted to fix later down the line)